# Displaying post per day

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I have the code displayed below.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<a class="vissted" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="hovereffect">
<div class="thumbnail">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('singles', array( 'class'  => "img-responsive")); ?>
<div class="overlay">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>
<div class="caption">
<div class="ratings">
<p class="pull-right"> </p>
<p>
Watch Video
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>     

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This code just displays EVERY post on my website, which is cool and all but I am looking to take it to the next level. How can I make it so that it displays post per day so for example.

[image]

You see in the top corner it displays the date of the post, I would love for it to do this on my website then limit to 1 week but display each result in a new block.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the wordpress query you should add the date that you want like so:

```
$current_month = date('m');
$current_year = date('Y');
$current_day = date('d');
$my_query = new WP_Query((array('year'=>date('Y'),'monthnum'=>date('m'),'day'=>date('d'),'posts_per_page'=>-1 ));
```

You can change the current_month, current_year, current_day variables by whatever day you want.